# how to catch symbol lookup error

Tags: c++

How can i catch an symbol lookup error in my code so currently my program crashes?

```
void main()
{
  try {
    dlopen("shared.so", RTLD_LAZY);
    /** 
      now running a function in this shared object and 
      this function calls a undefined reference
      and then it crashes but i want to go in the catch block
    */
  } catch(...) {
  }
}
```

Comment: ..How about checking the return value?

Comment: its just a short snippet dlopen returns a valid handle and the function in this shared object works well until the unreferenced is called

Answer (score 6):

`dlopen` is `C` function. It doesn't throw any `exception`.

```
void *dlopen(const char *filename, int flag);
```

From `man dlopen`

> If dlopen() fails for any reason, it returns NULL.

So, check return value for `NULL`.

So, for check, that symbol exists you should use

```
void *dlsym(void *handle, const char *symbol);
```

> If the symbol is not found, in the specified library or  any  of  the  libraries
>        that  were  automatically loaded by dlopen() when that library was loaded, **dlsym() returns NULL**.  (The search performed by dlsym()
>        is breadth first through the dependency tree of these libraries.)  **Since the value of the symbol could actually be NULL (so that a
>        NULL  return  from dlsym() need not indicate an error), the correct way to test for an error is to call dlerror() to clear any old
>        error conditions, then call dlsym(), and then call dlerror() again, saving its return value into a  variable,  and  check  whether
>        this saved value is not NULL**.

Comment: no it does not fail because it just fails if i call the unreferenced function and that can happen sometimes

Comment: its not unreal the shared.so uses functions which couldt be implemented in another lib or in the main programm so dlopen will deliver an valid handle just if you will call a function in the shared.so which can nowhere found then it crashes

Comment: @helmi `dlopen()` will fail to open libraries with unresolved references. It won't give you junk answers. If you're seeing crashes you probably have other problems elsewhere.

Comment: it will not fail if it opens with RTLD_LAZY flag!!